# resize image to fit in a div + keep ratio + centered horizontally and vertically + rounded corners

Tags: jquery, html, css

**The Problem:**

1. resize image to fit in a div - solved
2. keep ratio - solved
3. centered horizontally and vertically - solved
4. rounded corners

   a) rectangular images - solved

   **b) banner images - !!! impossiburu !!!**

So the question is: How do I get rid of the rectangular corners of the images? Please take a look at here to see the problem:  **>>> http://jsfiddle.net/infoman/5fzET/3/ <<<**

In other words: The corners of the image are round but they are not at the end of the div but beyond it. I need the image to be rounded at the lines where the div ends.

**HTML**

```
test image ratio w/h = 4
<div>
    <img id="myimg" src='http://placehold.it/200x50' draggable="false"/>
</div>

<br/>

test image ratio w/h = 0.25
<div>
    <img id="myimg" src='http://placehold.it/50x200' draggable="false"/>
</div>

<br/>

test image ratio w/h = 1 but small  
<div> 
    <img id="myimg" src='http://placehold.it/50x50' draggable="false"/>
</div>

<br/>

test image ratio w/h = 1 perfect fit
<div>
    <img id="myimg" src='http://placehold.it/300x300' draggable="false"/>
</div>

<br/>

test image ratio w/h = 1 much too big
<div>
    <img id="myimg" src='http://placehold.it/2000x2000' draggable="false"/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    border: solid 1px green;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

div img {
    outline: solid 1px red;
}

.fillwidth {
    width: 100%; 
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    /*top*/
}

.fillheight { 
    height: 100%; 
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
    /*left*/
}


.fillfull { 
    height: 300px; 
    width: 300px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('img[id^="myimg"]').each(function() {
    var imgWidth = $(this).width(),
        imgHeight = $(this).height(),
        imgRatio = imgWidth / imgHeight,
        imgWidthTop = (((300 / imgWidth) * imgHeight) / 2) * -1 + 300 / 2,
        imgHeightLeft = (((300 / imgHeight) * imgWidth) / 2) * -1 + 300 / 2;


    switch (true) {
    case (imgRatio === 1):
        $(this).addClass('fillfull');
        break;
    case (imgRatio < 1):
        $(this).addClass('fillwidth');
        $(this).css('top', imgWidthTop);
        break;
    case (imgRatio > 1):
        $(this).addClass('fillheight');
        $(this).css('left', imgHeightLeft);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
});​
```

**Try & Fail:**

1. clip : http://jsfiddle.net/infoman/5fzET/4/

Comment: Can you be clearer on what the problem is?

Comment: I don't see a problem. Nor did I see a question. What are you asking?

Comment: border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;

Comment: please take a look at the results with your own eyes here: http://jsfiddle.net/infoman/5fzET/3/ banner images get out of the bounds of the div

Comment: So your question is "How do I avoid clipping"? And even then, what kind of display do you want when you've got a size mismatch?

Comment: no I tried clipping but didn't get rid of the problem of "not round corners": http://jsfiddle.net/infoman/5fzET/4/ on size mismatch -> stretch the smallest value (width or height) to fill the div -> keep the ratio -> show the center of the oversized image in the div (pseudo clipping) -> round corners :/?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
```

You can add this to the div as well as the image(s).

Comment: please take a look at the results with your own eyes here: jsfiddle.net/infoman/5fzET/3 banner images get out of the bounds of the div

Comment: here's how they look for me: http://grab.by/hhnO .. i think they all look fine?  how do yours look?

Comment: I look at it in chrome and while it is working fine with rectangular images it doesn't work with banners. Not even with -webkit-border-radius: 10px; I guess this might be a bug or a nasty feature

Comment: I'd love to have a solution that works in every modern up to date browser and the internet explorer

Answer (score 0):

Simpler solution:

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/EdHQh/

HTML:

```
<div class='container'>
    <img class='resize_fit_center' src='...' />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 115px;
    height: 115px;
    line-height: 115px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid orange;
}
.resize_fit_center {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a start to your answer. The code below show how to set the class of a images parent element (which is what you need).

```
$('img[id^="myimg"]').each(function() {
var imgWidth = $(this).width(),
    imgHeight = $(this).height(),
    imgRatio = imgWidth / imgHeight,
    imgWidthTop = (((300 / imgWidth) * imgHeight) / 2) * -1 + 300 / 2,
    imgHeightLeft = (((300 / imgHeight) * imgWidth) / 2) * -1 + 300 / 2;

      //  alert(imgRatio);

switch (true) {
case (imgRatio < 1.1 && imgRatio > .99):
    $(this).addClass('fillfull');
    break;
case (imgRatio < 1):
    $(this).addClass('fillwidth');
    $(this).css('top', imgWidthTop);
    //$(this).css('clip', 'rect(100px 0 100px 0)');
    $(this).parent().addClass('bev');

    break;
case (imgRatio > 1):
    //$(this).css('clip', 'rect(0 100px 0 100px)');
    $(this).addClass('fillheight');
    $(this).css('left', imgHeightLeft);
    $(this).parent().addClass('bev');

    break;
default:
    break;
}
});
```

---

```
 .bev {
    border: solid 1px green;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }

 div img {
     outline: solid 1px red;
 }

 .fillwidth {
    width: 100%; 
    max-height: 99999px;
    position: relative;
    /*top*/
 }

 .fillheight { 
    height: 100%; 
    max-width: 99999px;
    position: relative;
    /*left*/
  }


 .fillfull { 
     height: 300px; 
     width: 300px;
 }
```

you could have serval different classes with differnt corners beveled or you could use javascript to change the style attributes. I hope this helps

Comment: in my example the images fill 100% of the box. They don't fit it in your example.