# One centred image on an html page

Tags: html

I am trying to write an html page that I can put any image url into, and it displays that image with a black background, centred vertically and horizontally on the page.

I have this:

```
<html>
<body style="background: black;">

<img src="http://i.imgur.com/n8o1E.png" style="display: block; margin: auto; max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%">

</body>
</html>
```

Which does the job right for images that are taller and thinner than the page, but it doesn't centre things vertically. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
html, body, #wrapper {
       height:100%;
       width: 100%;
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
       border: 0;
    }
    #wrapper td {
       vertical-align: middle;
       text-align: center;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
   <table id="wrapper">
      <tr>
         <td><img src="logo.png" alt="" /></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works for images that are shorter than the window, but when they're taller, they don't size down. I don't know why.

Comment: for that you need to resize image by jquery. here is the link. http://davejay.exit42design.com/entry/Design/44/

Comment: or refer to this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13232247/resize-image-to-fit-in-a-div-keep-ratio-centered-horizontally-and-vertically